# How can I cancel a scheduled gift delivery on steam?

Tags: steam

I've set up a scheduled gift on steam. Now I want to recall it. How can I do that?

Comment: The question body is there for a reason, so you can give more detail. Don't just point back to the title.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill what could I still add? I want to cancel a scheduled delivery gift on steam

Comment: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6643-QEUV-0459?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** This answer is outdated. [You'll find the late 2017 version of it here.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/320757/can-steam-gifts-be-rescheduled-under-the-new-gift-system-introduced-on-may-3-20?noredirect=1#comment456625_320757)

---

Old answer:

> 1. You go into your steam inventory.

The game should still be in your inventory, because it's not accepted yet. (It can't because it is scheduled) so:

> 2. You click on the game that is planned to be gifted
> 3. You click on "manage gift..."
> 4. Select "Return the gift to your account" and press "Next"

The result: The gift is back in your inventory and wont be gifted.